# What is the point of sub request at all?

Tags: http, webserver

Seems most web server support **subrequest**.

I found here's one question about sub request:

[Subrequest for PHP-CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438154/subrequest-for-php-cgi)

But what is the point of sub request at all,when is that kind of thing really useful?

Is it defined in http protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache subrequests can be used in your e.g. PHP application with [`virtual`](http://php.net/virtual)() to access resources from the same server. The resource gets processed from Apache normally as normal requests are, but you don't have the overhead of sending a full HTTP request on the network interface.

Less overhead is probably the only reason one would want to use it instead of a real HTTP request.

Edit: The resources are processed by apache, which means that the apache modules are used if configured. You can request a `mod_perl` or `mod_ruby` processed resource from PHP.

Comment: when do we need that? Why not request for that resource directly?

Comment: @cweiske Subrequests can be useful for any kind of RESTful cross-reference resource. Such as when someone needs to acquire a merged resource. Your app can then use subrequests to bring in the other resources, without needing to create endless models or controllers for edge cases. There are tradeoffs though, so one would benchmark different ways of doing things.